# Wordpress and "pretty permalink"

Tags: categories, permalinks

I've installed wordpress and set permalink structure to

```
/%category%/%post_id%_%postname%
```

I've also used 'No Category Base' plugin

I can list all posts in category 'my-cat' on archive page
//www.mysite.com/my-cat :)

but I just found out that this page returned same content
//www.mysite.com/anything/my-cat

//www.mysite.com/anything1/my-cat

//www.mysite.com/anything2/my-cat

Is this normal for wordpress?
Is there a way for //www.mysite.com/anything/my-cat ro return a 404 error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to say that mysite.com/my-cat and mysite-com/category/my-cat is showing you the same content?

Comment: Not only,
mysite-com/anyting/more/crap//my-cat gives the same page

Comment: I think if you just leave permalink structure to %postname% only it would solve the issuse, and your category will still be displayed, but as far as I know it won't make this behaviour, just suggestion you can try